# Aggregate function SUM returning different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions

I have following sample database schema

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKNxY.jpg

[image]

I want: 
**A) All sales, group by Users. 

B) Discounts, group by users.**

I am using following queries: 
**FOR A:**

```
    SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName, Sum(d.Quantity * i.Price) AS 'Sales'
FROM OrderDetails d
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
INNER JOIN Item i ON i.ItemID = d.ItemID
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = o.UserID
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserName
```

**RESULT:**

UserID  UserName Sales 
1   Mobeen  11060
2   Cashier 25960

**FOR B:**

```
    SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName, Sum(r.DiscountAmount) AS Discounts
FROM Receipt r
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = r.OrderID
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = o.UserID
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserName
```

**RESULT:**

UserID  UserName Discounts 
1   Mobeen  50
2   Cashier 310

BUT Then I decided to combine both queries but now the problem is that **I am getting different results.**
The query is as below:

```
    SELECT u.UserID,
    u.UserName,
    Sum(d.Quantity * i.Price) AS 'Sales',
    Sum(r.DiscountAmount) AS 'Discounts'
FROM OrderDetails d
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
INNER JOIN Item i ON i.ItemID = d.ItemID
INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = o.UserID
INNER JOIN Receipt r ON r.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserName
```

**Result:**

UserID  UserName Sales Discounts 
1   Mobeen  2270    50 
2   Cashier 25760   430

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are summing along multiple dimensions.  If you want to combine them, use subqueries:

```
select s.userID, s.userName, s.Sales, d.Discounts
from (SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName, Sum(d.Quantity * i.Price) AS 'Sales'
      FROM OrderDetails d
           INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
           INNER JOIN Item i ON i.ItemID = d.ItemID
           INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = o.UserID
           GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserName
     ) s join
     (SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName, Sum(r.DiscountAmount) AS Discounts
      FROM Receipt r
           INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = r.OrderID
           INNER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = o.UserID
       GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserName
     ) d
     on s.userId = d.userId and s.userName = d.userName
```

I think what is happening is that you are multiplying the receipt records for each item.  You need to be very careful when bringing together data naively using joins.  For such aggregations, subqueries are your friend.

If you need to get all the rows (i.e., there may be mismatches on either side), switch the join to a `full outer join` and use:

```
select coalesce(s.userId, d.userId) as userId, coalesce(s.userName, d.userName) as userName, . . .
```

Comment: +1 lol, I was just about to post an almost identical answer :)

Comment: @Gordon There is a slight mistake/typo in the post that d.Discount in main select should be d.Discounts

Answer (score 0):

The inner join to receipts is probably excluding some orders (not all orders have receipts, right) and double counting others (one order may have many receipts?)

Comment: Yes in my current database, not all orders have receipt but in the real scenario (after deployment) all orders will be having one receipt. And to second point, no, one order may have only one receipt.